# vertical alignment of text issue inside list item <li>

Tags: css

**Here is an example** http://dabblet.com/gist/3433883.

In this example my question is how make the last text "some text" inside `<li>` make vertically aligned without wrapping it in extra element. looking with IE7+ compatibility.

I already know that i can achieve this if i wrap that in a `span` and give `vertical-align:middle` but i'm just curious if it's possible without that.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><span class="icon"></span><b>bold text</b>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {list-style:none}
li {background:yellow}
.icon {background:url(http://www.gfdl.noaa.gov/pix/user_images/kd/qt_icon.png);
        display:block;
        height:32px;
        width:32px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:10px;
        vertical-align:middle}
b {vertical-align:middle}
```

**Edit: (after some answers)**

if i remove the vertical-align:middle on the `<b>`-tag. i get uneven spacing

[image]

Comment: Dabblet never works for me on Chrome. Here's a jsFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/ECYMN/

Comment: @Blender Just FYI. I'm also using Chrome (windows) but Dabblet working fine for me.

Comment: See my edit, you are measuring the wrong glyphs. Add a lowercase **y** or **p** and you will see that the text has even spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the vertical-align:middle on the `<b>`-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `vertical-align` to the highest element (normally `IMG` tags, but in your case a`SPAN` with a background image) should be enough, you can safely remove it on the `<b>` tag. Try this CSS as a proof of concept:

```
ul {
    list-style:none
}
li {
    background:yellow;
}
.icon {
    background:pink;
    height:48px;
    width:32px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/tVtKD/

Tested in IE7+

**UPDATE**

In opposite of what the OP thinks, this text does not have uneven spacing, you just need to measure the right glyphs. From the top of a capital letter to the bottom of a lowercase **y** or **p**. Se this enlarged image, it has exactly 15 px space on both sides.:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the `vertical-align` to the `li`.

```
ul {list-style:none}
li {background:yellow;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.icon {background:url(http://www.gfdl.noaa.gov/pix/user_images/kd/qt_icon.png);
        display:block;
        height:32px;
        width:32px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:10px;
        vertical-align:middle}
```

[image]

Comment: That's because you still have the <b> in there. Remove that and it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/ECYMN/6/

Comment: @JitendraVyas you should remove CSS rule for `b`, not element in HTML markup

Comment: @kobaltz - OK http://jsfiddle.net/ECYMN/6/ but now the whole text is not vertically centered. bottom has more spacing then top.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `line-height` to vertically align text within `<li>` tag:

```
ul {list-style:none}
li {background:yellow; line-height:32px;}
.icon {background:url(http://www.gfdl.noaa.gov/pix/user_images/kd/qt_icon.png);
    display:block;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align:middle}
```

This is my personal preference to align text vertically using `line-height`, because it works equally good on Windows, Mac and Linux platforms - fonts are different (especially on Mac) and by explicitly specifying `line-height` you make sure lines are aligned identically on all platforms.

Comment: @JitendraVyas -- please note that I've also removed `vertical-align` for `b` to achieve correct result. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tRpL/

Comment: see my comment at kobaltz's answer